# Difference Between Two Tikhonov Regularization Schemes

Tags: linear-model, regularization, tikhonov-regularization

For the solution of $Ax = b$, where $A$ is a square matrix, what is the difference between these two regularized solutions:

- $x = (A + \alpha I)^{-1}b$ -- coressponding to eq.3 below
- $x = (A^TA + \alpha I)^{-1}A^Tb$ -- corresponding to eq.2 below with $K(w) = A, K(-w) = A^T$

In the following reference:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0041555382900945#

[image]

for positive symmetric difference kernels (for example a Gaussian kernel) the first form of regularization is promoted as a simplified Tikhonov regularization (in statistical models we usually use $p = 0$ for $M(w) = I$).

**Is the simplification just an approximation or is it equivalent to the second form above?** Basically I am trying to understand the connection between discretized versions that we use in statistics and the continuous versions that are used in integral equations.

This question is related to this

[Regularized linear vs. RKHS-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328253/regularized-linear-vs-rkhs-regression)

where the answer claims a substantial difference, in contrast to the above recommendation.

Comment: If you assume nothing about $A,$ there can be profound differences.  Compare the solutions when, for instance, $A$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: The second equation is standard for ridge regression and $A$ need not be square. The first is the standard for kernel ridge regression (and SVM/gaussian process, kernel methods with ridging) where $A$ is a square similarity matrix of the cases in the data.